# R Calculate big NOR matrix

Tags: r, performance, matrix, logical-operators

I have a big square matrix in R:

```
norMat <- matrix(NA, nrow=1024, ncol=1024)
```

This empty matrix needs to be filled with the sum of all equal bits of all matrix index pairs.

So I need to calculate the logical NOR for `i`(rowIndex) and `j`(colIndex) and sum the result,e.g:

```
sum(intToBits(2)==intToBits(3))
```

Currenty, I have this function which fills the matrix:

```
norMatrix <- function()
{
  matDim=1024
  norMat <<- matrix(NA, nrow=matDim, ncol=matDim)
  for(i in 0:(matDim-1)) {
    for(j in 0:(matDim-1)) {
      norMat[i+1,j+1] = norsum(i,j)
    }
  }

  return(norMat)
}
```

And here's the `norsum` function:

```
norsum <- function(bucket1, bucket2)
{
  res = sum(intToBits(bucket1)==intToBits(bucket2))

  return(res)
}
```

Is this an efficient solution to fill the matrix?
I'm in doubt since on my machine this takes over 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this is a great opportunity for the `*apply` functions. Here's one solution that's a bit faster than 5 minutes.

First, proof of concept, non-square solely for clarity of dimensions.

```
nc <- 5
nr <- 6
mtxi <- sapply(seq_len(nc), intToBits)
mtxj <- sapply(seq_len(nr), intToBits)
sapply(1:nc, function(i) sapply(1:nr, function(j) sum(mtxi[,i] == mtxj[,j])))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   32   30   31   30   31
# [2,]   30   32   31   30   29
# [3,]   31   31   32   29   30
# [4,]   30   30   29   32   31
# [5,]   31   29   30   31   32
# [6,]   29   31   30   31   30
```

Assuming that these are correct, the full meal deal:

```
n <- 1024
mtx <- sapply(seq_len(n), intToBits)
system.time(
  ret <- sapply(1:n, function(i) sapply(1:n, function(j) sum(mtx[,i] == mtx[,j])))
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.25    0.00    3.36
```

You don't technically need to pre-calculate `mtxi` and `mtxj`. Though `intToBits` does not introduce much overhead, I think it's silly to recalculate every time.

My system is reasonable (i7 6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz), win10_64, R-3.3.2 ... nothing too fancy.

Comment: Thx, a really huge speed up!